# Is it possible to have a inflection on a vertical asymptote?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I found the derivative of a function to be $f'(x)=8/x^3$ and thus its second derivative as $f''(x)=0/3x^2$. After setting the second derivative to zero and doing the substitution into the parent function, it seems that there's a point of inflection at $(0,0)$.

The only issue is that the graph has a vertical asymptote at $x=0$. Does this mean I messed up somewhere?

Comment: If the first derivative is as given, the second is not.

Comment: The derivative of a quotient is not the quotient of the derivatives.

Comment: Are you saying I divided the two? I thought I'd just use the power rule on both the numerator and denominator because it was evident that it would equal zero. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Yes, very incorrect. The derivative of $\frac{8}{x^3}$ is $-\frac{24}{x^4}$.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm going to try using the quotient rule and see if my new answer for the second derivative matches yours.
Either way, the point of inflection would still equal to (0,0) and my dilemma would still exist.

Comment: We are looking at $8x^{-3}$. Use the power rule. The point $(0,0)$ is not even on the curve.

Comment: Typo earlier. Your function, if the first derivative was right, is concave down on $(-\infty,0)$, also on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: ummm $\dots$ define asymptote.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you did mess up, though I do not know where exactly.

If
$$
f'(x)=\frac{8}{x^3}
$$
then
$$
f''(x)=-\frac{24}{x^4}
$$

The curve from which you got $f'(x)$ does not even pass through $(0,0)$ let alone having an inflection point there.
$$
f(x)=-4 \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{a^2}\right)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f(x)=\infty
$$

In fact, $f(x)$ has no inflection points at all.